# Android google maps v2 performance issues

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

i'm struggling with a problem and tried to solve it by weeks but without a solution that meets my needs. My problem it's I've to add multiple markers (>=6000) to my map and after all the ideas/suggestions and investigation i'm still with performance issues, because adding a marker to the map it's on the main thread even when the marker it's constructed in a background thread.

**Assumptions&Progress:**

- I've allready read:[Too many markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers)
- I'am using clustering
- I'am only adding markers of the visible region to limit the amount of markers and suppress unnecessary load
- I've already tried using Handlers and now i'am using Asynctask because i realize they're a little bit faster (or it's just placebo)
- At the moment i'am adding markers in the onProgressUpdate (one by one) but i've allready tried to send a List and add the markers in the OnPostExecute(result) but the performance its worst.

**My code:**

```
private class MarkerTask extends AsyncTask<Positions, MarkerOptions, Void> {
    Projection projection;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        projection = mMap.getProjection();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Positions... params) {
        List<Vessel> positionsList = new ArrayList<Vessel>(params[0].getList());
        LatLngBounds bounds = projection.getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;

        for (int i = 0; i < positionsList.size(); i++) {
                if (bounds.contains(locationLatLng) && interval.contains(DateTimeUtc)) {
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.position(locationLatLng);
                markerOptions.title(name);
                markerOptions.rotation(getHeading());
                markerOptions.snippet(id);
                markerOptions.anchor(Constants.MARKER_ANCHOR_CENTER, Constants.MARKER_ANCHOR_CENTER);

                publishProgress(markerOptions);
                positionsList.remove(i);
                if (isCancelled())
                    break;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(MarkerOptions... values) {
        mMap.addMarker(values[0]);
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(onMarkerClick());
    }
```

Any suggestions how to improve the performance??

Comment: I like to know why this question it's down voted! It's a real question well formed and it's an issue which too many developers are facing

Comment: To enhance maps performance watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pCh62wr6m0 and other videos. Performance issues are lot of times app specific as well. So you might want to check performance best practices and other information on optimizing app performance.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/best-performance.html to start with. Suggesting to check over all app performance as with marker clustering in use maps performance does not have issues even with 1000+ markers. You don't seem to have even that many.

Comment: @KayAnn i know the best pratices but i took a look just for the case that i was forgetting something but no, i changed my question because it's not >=60 markers but >=6000 markers. And yes i'am using clustering

Comment: Have you  looked at this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/